# Can I delete the default application_controller installed with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create a new app there is a default controller added called application_controller.

Is this holding important information or can I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, every other controller you generate will inherit from the `ApplicationController`, so you kinda need it. Is your interest purely academic, or are you having problems with it?

Comment: I'm just learning how to use Rails for the first time, and am just trying to get rid of unnecessary clutter is all. Based on what you said it sounds rather important..

Comment: I'd say there's not much clutter in a freshly generated rails app. Everything has a meaning. You'll have better experience by reading [a good book](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) on the matter.